# Create injected object at the start of the application, not at the request

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I created an ASP.NET Core API project like below, launched it, and waited for several seconds. "Creating XXX" was not printed until I requested the API URL. Can I tell ASP.NET Core to create a `MyXXX` after it started whether there is a request or not? The reason is that it could take a while for creating/initialising `MyXXX`, and if it is done before requests, the first request will be faster.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton<IXXX, MyXXX>();
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult<string> Get([FromServices]IXXX xxx)
{
    return xxx.Value.ToString();
}

public interface IXXX
{
    int Value { get; set; }
}

class MyXXX : IXXX
{
    public MyXXX()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Creating XXX");
    }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes of course you can do it yourself !

```
var concrete= new MyXXX();
services.AddSingleton<IXXX>(concrete);
```